# Out-file export to a network location powershell

Tags: powershell, export

I am having an issue trying to output a file with PowerShell, I can export the file to the computer's local drives however when I want to export it to a network location it will not let me.

I receive the following error:

```
Access to the path '\\fmadt-prod-web5\e$\ftproot\customer\temp\SiteLists\Classic\Hosted1.txt' is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
$list2 | Format-Table -a -Property "WebAppName", "Version", "State"| Out-File '\\fmadt-prod-web5\e$\ftproot\customer\temp\SiteLists\Classic\Hosted1.txt' -force
```

Is it possible to export to a network location? The user I am using has admin access to that location as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a UNC path, but you can map a `PSDrive` to that location and use that:

```
New-PSDrive -Name dest -Root \\fmadt-prod-web5\e$\ftproot\customer\temp\SiteLists\Classic -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Then:

```
| out-file dest:\Hosted1.txt
```

Use the `-Credential` parameter of `New-PSDrive` if you need to access the drive using alternate credentials.

Comment: I now receive an error that the root does not exist or is not a folder, I have verified they location is precise and is in existence. I am using the credentials of server admin on the network and servers as well. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you most certainly can output to unc paths, I regularly use those at work. This almost looks like you don't, or the account you are running the script as doesn't, have access to the directory.

E$ refers to the admin share on a server, try actually sharing that directory via windows shares or run the script using an account that is in the administrators group on the relevant server. Also, I always use double quotes for paths because then you can include variables -- force of habit :)